# Does Redis provide Expiration and an Expiration callback?

Tags: .net, redis, queue, servicestack, redistogo

I'm starting a green field project. In it, we would like to have a **QUEUE** that has expiries. So I add an key and that item expires in .. say .. 20 mins.

The queue is expected to be pretty large. 10's of thousands of keys with different expiry times.

Straight away I thought of maybe using [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/) and of course, Redis :)

So far, this is hopefully going to be hosted on `AppHarbor + RavenDb + RedisToGo`. Redis Key will be the RavenDb Id's. (strings - eg. `users/1` or whatever)

#### Questions

1. Can I leverage SS.Redis to add items to a redis queue with an expiry? (I'm assuming, yes. for eg. typedClient.ExpiresAt(..))
2. Can I leverage RedisToGo as the cloud hosted redis provider and use SS.Redis as the client? (again, assuming yes and yes)
3. When an item expires, can i get it to do a REST GET or POST to some URL? - so i can 'handle' an expiry? (No idea).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In redis, it is the **key** that has the expiry, not individual items in a list/set/hash/etc. If you have a single queue (I assume that is a *list* in redis terminology, pushing/popping at different ends), then your expiry applies to *all* items in that same queue. There isn't really a good metaphor for a list (etc) that would allow per-item expiry. Frankly, the easiest thing is probably to include the logical expiry in the payload, and just discard items as you pop them if they are overdue
2. As the client has access to the server over the selected port, you should be ok - regardless of the particular client and server/provider; but it would presumably be trivial to verify this if you have those services.
3. Redis at the current time doesn't include any expiry trigger functionality, **but** this has been proposed and (seemingly) accepted for the 2.8 release ([see discussion here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/redis-db/7jEUTqeSkSs/Cq8a-UbZTSwJ)); redis won't **itself** do any posts to urls, but hypothetically you could just listen on the event channel and do that in *your* code

But again, it comes back to the issue of expiry on keys vs items.

Comment: It's all expiry on KEYS. The item can be anything for the topic of this convo. It's just that a Key .. has some value .. and they Key will expire in 20 mins or 5 hours or whatever. Which leaves us with => trigger functionality has been proposed. So that means NO (as of the time of this post). Drats .. but oh well. ... er ... any suggestions for something else?

Comment: @Pure.Krome if you are just using keys, I'm not quite sure how you're using it as a queue, unless you have a list that contains just the keys to dequeue, and then do a second fetch (which btw could be scripted quite nicely via lua in 2.6 - i.e. pop, then try to "get" - if it comes back nil (expired), then pop the next, etc)

Comment: @Pure.Krome as for proactive notifications: again, no at the current time, but you could post on the redis group asking for an update / eta

Answer (score 0):

try using a sorted set (ZSET) for your queue - with a timestamp as the SCORE. when you pick jobs off the queue with ZREVRANGEBYSCORE, you can check the timestamp the job was submitted into the queue and if it's too old, you can simply ignore the job.